# Other uses for a Proxy?

Tags: proxy

I am currently studying computer science for GCSE, and according to, http://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/zkhykqt/revision/3, a proxy can be setup to distribute viruses? From what I know, its something that sits in-between your computer, and the internet, and is also used to mask your current location and IP address, I can't think how it can be used to entice people to download viruses if its simply a server, that can be connected by making a few entries into the network settings, is BBC correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret what the BBC are saying as more like a phishing attack. You think you're connecting to a legitimate website but it's really a fake copy that tries to entice you to download some sort of malware or virus.

However, at least with HTTP traffic, when you explicitly configure your machine to use a proxy you're delegating the responsibility of fetching any web content to the proxy server. Instead of fetching content from the webserver, you connect to the proxy and basically say "please fetch this for me".

A malicious proxy server could then theoretically return anything it wanted to instead of the original content. There are example proxy servers that do "humourous" things to HTTP traffic such as blur any images, turn them upside down, etc. and also proxy servers that do the opposite of what the BBC suggests in that they scan any web content to make sure it doesn't contain viruses or malware.